# Why does JFrame.repaint() reset graphics but JPanel.repaint() does not?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, repaint

I have a simple animation:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Animation extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    int x = 0, y;
    JFrame frame;
    int delay, xInc, yInc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Animation();
    }

    public Animation() {
      frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setSize(600, 400);
      frame.setTitle("Animation");
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      y = frame.getHeight() / 4;
      frame.add(this);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      float fps = 75f;
      delay = (int) (1000f / fps);
      yInc = xInc = (int) (delay / 3);
      Timer timer = new Timer(delay, this);
      timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (x + 5 >= getWidth())
        xInc = -1 * Math.abs(xInc);
      if (x - 5 <= 0)
        xInc = Math.abs(xInc);
      if (y + 5 >= getHeight())
        yInc = -1 * Math.abs(yInc);
      if (y - 5 <= 0)
        yInc = Math.abs(yInc);

      frame.repaint(); // versus just "repaint()"
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      g.fillOval(x += xInc, y += yInc, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Calling `frame.repaint()` as shown makes the circle simply "move" to the next location, while if I call `repaint()` (the JPanel's method) it draws a line 10px wide (i.e. it doesn't reset/clear the graphics at all). I understand that `JFrame.repaint()` calls every component's `paintComponent()`, `paintChildren()`, and `paintBorder()` methods, but what method or part of this call sequence results in clearing the contents of the JFrame before repainting? Why doesn't the JPanel method behave the same?

In any case, would it be more common in this situation to call the JFrame method, or the JPanel's and clear the last circle with the graphics manually before redrawing?

Comment: Normally you have `super.paintComponent(g);` at the start of your overridden `paintComponent` method. That at least will paint over whatever was there before.

Comment: I don't see where `repaint()` is ever called on the panel..

Comment: @AndrewThompson It isn't, it was more a hypothetical; if/when I call `repaint()` rather than `frame.repaint()`, etc.

Comment: @khelwood So you essentially paint the component with a blank graphics before painting? Tried it, and it does give me the same behavior as `frame.repaint()`. That does answer my last paragraph, how about the "why" question?

Comment: @khelwood answered the "why". They behave differently because you have failed to call `super.paintComponent(g)` in your overridden paintComponent method.